# What do we mean by Derivative of linear function is a constant function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

I've the text below given in my notes:

> **Derivative of linear function:** *Let $R:X\to Y$ be a linear function .Then $R':X\to L(X,Y)$ is a constant function with the constant value $R\in L(X,Y)$ i.e. $R'(a)=R$ for all*   **a** $\in X$.That is , $$R'(a)=R$$ for all **a,x** $\in X$.

Can anyone explain the above definition with help of an example clearly stating what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the derivative (if exists) of $f$ in $x_0\in X$ is a linear function
$$f'(x_0):X\longrightarrow Y$$
s.t.
$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+o(h).$$
When $f=R$ linear, by this linearity
$$R(x_0+h)=R(x_0)+R(h)$$
and
$$f(x_0)=R(x_0),$$
$$f'(x_0)(h)=R(h),$$
$$o(h)=0.$$

Example:
$$R(x_1,x_2)=\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&4}\pmatrix{x_1\cr x_2}=\cdots$$
and the matrix of $R'$ is given by the partial derivatives of $R$...

Comment: This is something giving proof of what I said...but can you please help explaining using example how is derivative of a linear function a constant function as asked in question..

Comment: @cool, $R'$ is constant because takes the same value ($R$) for all $x_0\in X$ ($\forall x_0\in X\ R'(x_0)=R$). Try yourself with a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and $R(x)=Ax$ (x **column** vector).

Comment: didn't get how takes same value $(R)$ for all $x_0\in X$..

Comment: @cool, $R'(x_0)(h)=R(h)$ for all $h\in X$, so $R'(x_0)=R$.

Comment: @cool, your problem is very usual among the students. $R$ is a function but *also* the *value* of another function.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla can you please explain how you wrote $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+o(h).$ .what does $o(h)$ stand in this ...

Comment: @spectraa, some function $g$ s.t. $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)/h=0$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thanks for the reference...

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be a linear function of $x$.

In general, the function $f$ then takes the form

$$f(x) = mx + b$$

where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the y-intercept of the graph of $f$, which is nothing but a non-vertical line.

Differentiating:

$$f'(x) = m$$

which gives the derivative $f'$ as the slope of the line

$$y = f(x) = mx + b.$$

Comment: please help explaining how does it show that derivative is a constant function...

Comment: @coool, the slope of any non-vertical line is a real number (i.e., a constant).  Therefore, the derivative of a linear function, which is nothing else but the slope of the graph of the function, is constant.

Comment: thanks for explaining in $1$-D but the definition involves case having more than one-variable..